# How to plot multiple pie charts in a single image file python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My data is like:

```
{'Name': ['TC1', 'TC2', 'TC3'], 'Automated': ['12', '10', '8'], 'manual': ['2', '4', '6']}
```

Where TC denotes to TestClass and Automated denoted Automated tests and manual denoted manual testcases

Want to create a plot which creates 2 pie charts 1 for each TC having breakup of Automated Vs Manual.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your mentioning of 2 pie charts, I assume you want a separate one for "Automated" and "Manual". You can simply do something like this using `pandas.plot`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['TC1', 'TC2', 'TC3'], 'Automated': [12, 10, 8], 'manual': [2, 4, 6]})
df.set_index(['Name']).plot.pie(subplots=True, legend='', autopct='%.1f', figsize=(20, 10))
```

Output:

[image]

If you want a pie plot for each TC value, do this:

```py
(df.melt(id_vars = 'Name').pivot(columns='Name', index='variable', values='value')
 .plot.pie(subplots=True, legend='', autopct='%.1f', figsize=(20, 10)))
```

[image]